# Android Custom Adapter: list items only populated when scrolling

Tags: android, android-listview, android-adapter

I'm having an issue getting my list populated correctly by my custom ArrayAdapter (code below). As I understand it, my adapter is only populating the textviewResourceId when it is instanciated since I'm using constructor `Adapter(context, rowLayout, textViewResourceId, ArrayList<Items>)`, but the getView method is only called when rows that were not visible become visible.

This is causing an issue as, when my list is first showing, only the title of my article is showing, and I have to scroll all the way down the list and up for all the views in each row to be populated correctly (since that task is done in getView).

Can anyone point me in the right direction? How could I refactor this so all views in each visible row gets populated right away?

Code to my custom adapter:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ArticleArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Article> {

    private final Context context;
    private final ArrayList<Article> articles;
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private final int rowLayout;

    public ArticleArrayAdapter(Context context, int rowLayout, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<Article> articles) {
        super(context, rowLayout, textViewResourceId, articles);
        this.rowLayout=rowLayout;
        this.context = context;
        this.articles = articles;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View row = convertView;
        if (row == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
            row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.affichageitem, null);
        }
        else {
            TextView viewTitre = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.titre);
            TextView viewAuteur = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.auteur);
            TextView viewDate = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.date);
            ImageView viewLogo = (ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.category_logo);
            viewTitre.setText(articles.get(position).getTitle());
            viewAuteur.setText(articles.get(position).getCreator());
            viewDate.setText(articles.get(position).getDate());
            Drawable drawLogo = context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.logocat);
            viewLogo.setImageDrawable(drawLogo);
        }
        return super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
    }
}
```

Edited version:

```
public class ArticleArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Article> {

    private final Context context;
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private final int rowLayout;

    public ArticleArrayAdapter(Context context, int rowLayout,int textViewResourceId) {
        super(context, rowLayout, textViewResourceId);
        this.rowLayout=rowLayout;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View row = convertView;
        if (row == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
            row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.affichageitem, null);
        }
        else {
            TextView viewTitre = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.titre);
            TextView viewAuteur = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.auteur);
            TextView viewDate = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.date);
            ImageView viewLogo = (ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.category_logo);
            viewTitre.setText(getItem(position).getTitle());
            viewAuteur.setText(getItem(position).getCreator());
            viewDate.setText(getItem(position).getDate());
            Drawable drawLogo = context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.logocat);
            viewLogo.setImageDrawable(drawLogo);
        }
        return super.getView(position, convertView, parent); // <<- ONLY TITLES
        //return row; <<- EMPTY
    }
}
```

rowLayout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/category_logo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:contentDescription="@string/logo_desc"
        android:padding="20dp" />

    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/titre"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <LinearLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity=""
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <TextView
            android:id="@+id/auteur"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:textSize="12dp" />
            <TextView
            android:id="@+id/espace"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/espace"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:textSize="12dp" />
            <TextView
            android:id="@+id/date"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:textSize="12dp" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You should watch Android developer Romain Guy discuss [efficiency with adapters and `getView()`](http://www.google.com/events/io/2009/sessions/TurboChargeUiAndroidFast.html) to speed up your code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you are not populating new views. What happens is that Android may keep a fixed number of views which will be used for your list view. The views are recycled which is why it's impossible to "populate" all your views before they become visible. This line

```
if (view == null) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
    row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.affichageitem, null);
}
```

checks whether a view is being recycled or not. `null` means it's not, so if you get null you need to inflate a new view. Upto there your code's fine. However, you need to populate the view whether it's a newly inflated view or not. So you shouldn't have the else statement, just have

```
View row = convertView;
if (row == null) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
    row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.affichageitem, null);
}
TextView viewTitre = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.titre);
TextView viewAuteur = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.auteur);
TextView viewDate = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.date);
ImageView viewLogo = (ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.category_logo);
viewTitre.setText(getItem(position).getTitle());
viewAuteur.setText(getItem(position).getCreator());
viewDate.setText(getItem(position).getDate());
Drawable drawLogo = context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.logocat);
viewLogo.setImageDrawable(drawLogo);

return row;
```

The reason why it worked when you scrolled all the way down is that on your way back up `getView` was receiving recycled `views` and it jumped right into the else clause you had.

Answer (score 2):

You are using your own collection `ArrayList<Article>`.

Note that every `ArrayAdaper<foo>` already has data collection built in, where you can add by `add(foo)` or `addAll(List<foo>)` and clear it by `clear()` method.

Also, `ListView` can observe this data and refresh when changes happen to this data. Or explicitly when `notifyDataSetChanged()` is called on adapter.

Problem here is that you are accepting data in constructor, storing in yet another local variable, and `notifyDataSetChanged()` is not being called. You cannot call it from constructor as Object is still under construction.

So, Don't accept data in constructor. Inside `getView()` use `getItem(position)` to get `Article` item.

Add data externally like:

```
ArticleArrayAdapter adapter = new ArticleArrayAdapter(context,rowLayout,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
adapter.addAll(articles);
myListView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: Thank you for the advice, the built in data collection is working like a charm ! But still, I'm getting the same issue of empty rows on loading the new articles. I have to scroll to see a correct layout. After making the changes you suggested, I tried in getView to both return rows and return super.getView(position, convertView, parent). The first shows empty rows, the second shows only the title of the article. I guess the problem lies with what getView returns. Should I call notifyDataSetChanged() somewhere ? Also, what does textViewResourceId needs to be? One of the textViews in rowLayout ?

Comment: Don't use `super.getView()` it will just return a single text, Use `return row`. Problem might be in two places : in `getView()` or in Xml layout you inflate inside `getView()`.

Comment: Updated answer. use `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1` as default resource, It will show a simple text obtained from `toString()` of each `Article` object , when you don't provide custom row views.

Comment: I tried ArticleArrayAdapter(ListMenu.this, R.layout.rowLayout, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1), but I get the same result. Added my layout file in the question as well for reference.

Answer (score 1):

Looks correct to me - only thing: there is no need to call the superclass. Try to return your assembled view like that:

```
return row;
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried your suggestion, but it resulted in the first visible rows to be completely empty.

Comment: What does Logcat say when you print out the missing stuff like e.g your date? Does it show up?

Comment: Nothing shows up until I start scrolling. It seems as if getView is not called before I do.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View row = convertView;
    if (row==null){
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
        row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.affichageitem, null);
         convertView.setTag(row);
    }else{
        TextView viewTitre = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.titre);
        TextView viewAuteur = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.auteur);
        TextView viewDate = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.date);
        ImageView viewLogo = (ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.category_logo);
        viewTitre.setText(getItem(position).getTitle());
        viewAuteur.setText(getItem(position).getCreator());
        viewDate.setText(getItem(position).getDate());
        Drawable drawLogo = context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.logocat);
        viewLogo.setImageDrawable(drawLogo);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this similar kind of issue. I also found that without scrolling manually to the last of the list all views were not created. All items were null except visible items.So, I had to scroll down to the last of the list programmatically.

I have extended MyAdapter from BaseAdapter class.

```
mAdapter = new MyAdapter(this, mFinalContactList);
mListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

To auto scrolling to last with all listview created I have used following lines of code.

```
mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
mListView.setTranscriptMode(ListView.TRANSCRIPT_MODE_ALWAYS_SCROLL);
mListView.smoothScrollToPosition(mFinalContactList.size()-1);
```

**This might help some one who are trying auto scroll to the last.**

N.B. ***mListView.setSelection(position);*** method only can point the last list item if we set the position to last. But can not populate the list item from forst to last.

Thank you